# Force close after clicking Recaptcha

Tags: android, recaptcha

I got trouble force close in android development after click reCAPTCHA. this my response error code in logcat:

```
12-03 16:04:32.573 2678-2995/com.google.android.gms.ui E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
12-03 16:04:32.652 2678-2995/com.google.android.gms.ui E/eglCodecCommon:   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
12-03 16:04:32.704 2678-2995/com.google.android.gms.ui E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
12-03 16:04:32.732 2678-2995/com.google.android.gms.ui E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
12-03 16:04:32.772 2678-2995/com.google.android.gms.ui E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
```

this is my code for use reCAPTCHA for android

```
 protected  void handleSiteVerify(final String responseToken){
    String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.getBoolean("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(jsonObject.getBoolean("success")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("error-codes")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSON exception: " + ex.getMessage());

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error message: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("secret", SECRET_KEY);
            params.put("response", responseToken);
            return params;4
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            50000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(request);
}
```

every click reCAPTCHA on android after finished always force closed maybe you have an idea for my code .. please help me

Comment: Add the code please

Comment: done @Apuna12 i  :)

Comment: What is happening when you put a BP on try in OnResponse method?